# SSAS Two Data Sources in one Cube

Tags: ssas, olap, multidimensional-cube

I have 2 data source which is Hospital A and Hospital B that have same structure.

On Data Source View , I add same table for Hospital A and Hospital B like this ->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nURE2.png)

then I add `hospital_key` attribute in the fact table which are table **ADMISSIONS** to uniquely categorized by hospital.

then I set **ADMISSIONS** table as fact for each of the hospital. Then the cube would be like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxrNj.png)

My problem is

1. I able to visualize just one hospital only like this-> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g8Px.png)

How can I visualize for the both Hospitals? Please Help!

or Did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking is how to rationalise your source objects in the Data Source View?

If so, the tables have the same structure for both Hospitals so you could UNION them together in a named query e.g.

SELECT MyColumns, 1 AS hospital_key FROM AdmissionsTable1
UNION
SELECT MyColumns, 2 AS hospital_key FROM AdmissionsTable2

If needed, repeat for patients data.  I am assuming that you only need 1 Sexes table likewise.

Comment: Someone suggest me to create view first then use the view table as the data source

Comment: Yes,ideally I try and place all of my objects behind a view and then add the view to the data source view for simplicity.